# Alternatives to matplotlib tight_layout()? Or stop xlabels overrunning chart edge?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create an animation of a barplot in seaborn.

When I iterate over the data, creating and saving each uniquie dates barplot WITHOUT tight_layout == True every thing stays stationary but some labels are cut.

Using tight_layout == True is great and it fixes all these issues but there is one undesired consequence.

As the data values increase the X tick labels change, and matplot lib automatically formats the positions of the ticks which produces pretty good results BUT sometimes the final label overrunns the chart edge, which casues tight_layout to reduce the width of the chart to make room for the labels. Is there a way to use tight_layout while keeping the width of the chart static?

This is fine.

```
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
______________|
       |
   500,000
```

This causes me an issue, as the xticklabel overruns the chart edge, reducing the width of the chart so it matches the figsize.

```
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
___________|
          |
       500,000
```

Maybe if someone knows how to tell if an xticklabel's xpos > charts width then I could just remove the last tick in that instance. But I can't seem to get hold of this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to get round this. For anyone reading this here is my solution.

Create some Fake data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":[f"TESTING LABELS {x}" for x in range(30)]})
df["Data"] = np.random.randint(0,9999,len(df))
df
```

Plot the chart

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8),dpi=100)
ax = sns.barplot(x="Category", y="Data",data=df)
```

Notice how the labels overrun the chart edge.

[image: label test]

This can be fixed by first getting hold of the chart width (not the figure width)
Then iterating through the labels width and discarding any that are > chart width.

There are two options you can either remove the labels that overrun leaving the ticks

```
__________________________
|          |             |
value1    value2
```

or

remove the ticks altogether.

```
__________________________
|          |             
value1    value2
```

First get the chart (you need to call draw() or this fails)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8),dpi=100)
ax = sns.barplot(x="Category", y="Data",data=df)
ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
```

Get the chart width

```
chart_x1 = ax.get_window_extent().x1
```

Then use list comprehension to remove any that overrun.

#### To remove labels

```
ticks = [tick for tick in ax.get_xticklabels() if tick.get_window_extent().x1 < chart_x1]
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
```

[image: label removal]

#### To remove ticks

```
ticks = [tick.get_position()[0] for tick in ax.get_xticklabels() if tick.get_window_extent().x1 < chart_x1]
_ = ax.set_xticks(ticks)
```

[image]

Just to point out you probably wouldn't want to remove this labels beneath the bars but in my particular situation the bar is horizontal (this demonstration is not)

Complete code example for overrun ticks label removal:

```py
#set size
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8),dpi=100)
#define data and get axis
ax = sns.barplot(x="Category", y="Data",data=df)
#draw prior to x position retrieval 
ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
#chart max chart width
chart_x1 = ax.get_window_extent().x1
#use list comprehension to only select values that do not overrun 
ticks = [tick for tick in ax.get_xticklabels() if tick.get_window_extent().x1 < chart_x1]
#then set the tick labels
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
```